# Infinite template loading using Angular JS routeprovider

Tags: ruby, angularjs, sinatra, erb, routes

**Fixed It** checking for an xhr request fixed the infinite loop

```
get '/about' do
    erb :about, layout: !request.xhr?
end
```

---

I am using angular js and sinatra to create a page. Angular is handling my routes and calling the templates

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {templateUrl: '/home'}).
        when('/about', {templateUrl: '/about'}).
        when('/work', {templateUrl: '/work'}).
        when('/blog', {templateUrl: '/blog'}).
        when('/contact', {templateUrl: '/contact'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

When I go to */#/blog* , the template loads fine. The content is provided by sinatra

```
get '/blog' do
    'This is the work page!'
end
```

However, I get infinite view loads when doing the about page. The about page is provided by

```
get '/about' do
    erb :about
end
```

Comment: all i can do is confirm that your angular code looks fine. not that familiar with erb to know what erb :about does

Comment: Don't put the `:erb about` in the get loop. That is another page, with the `about` location. This is why you get the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
get '/about' do
    erb :about, layout: !request.xhr?
end
```

the previous code load the layout which contained the angular js code. the js code called the /about again and it repeated. Since the call from angular js route is xhr, checking it fixed the problem.